# Magento 1.7 Category pages description not appearing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have an odd problem: I have several categories and sub-categories on my site. In Manage categories, I have painstakingly inserted description and meta-desc for SEO. However, in the frontend, some category pages are displaying the description and meta-description fine; others are simply not showing the description block above the products; if I go into View Source in the browser, I see the meta description as the default site meta description rather than the specific meta description for the category page.

I have cleared all my cache and sessions data but the problem remains. Any ideas?

Thanks.
-TM

Comment: I am trying to delete all the cache files in var/cache but some of the files are not getting deleted. Could that be the problem? If so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Admin - System - Index Management - Category Flat Data - Reindex data. That should do it.